# Error while creating signup page to create user account in User_ table of Liferay 6.1?

Tags: java, jsp, web, liferay, portlet

I am facing problem while creating sign-up portlet in Liferay 6.1 and store user account in default `User_` table in database.

I am using default Liferay class `UserLocalServiceUtil` and its method `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(creatorUserId, companyId, autoPassword, password1, password2, autoScreenName, screenName, emailAddress, facebookId, openId, locale, firstName, middleName, lastName, prefixId, suffixId, male, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay, birthdayYear, jobTitle, groupIds, organizationIds, roleIds, userGroupIds, sendEmail, serviceContext);`

I face this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pwd.PwdToolkitUtil.validate(PwdToolkitUtil.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.validate(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:5405)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUserWithWorkflow(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:592)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUser(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:463)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
    at $Proxy96.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:445)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:316)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:105)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:366)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:382)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:315)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
...
```

Comment: Can you also post some code which is calling the `addUser` method? As Olaf Kock [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251203/468763) are you calling this code from `render` method or from your JSP? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You password1 or password2 is probably null, and the autoPassword is set to true. Liferay tries to validate the given passwords, and when comparing null values, comes a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to call this method from the render state of your portlet, directly from a jsp - you should do this from the action state, before rendering. During rendering you're not supposed to change any state.

Read about the portlet lifecycle where this is explained in more detail. In short: If you're used to do everything from jsps in servlets, you'll have to re-learn for portlets: There action and render are neatly separated states. Typically a portlet renders a lot more often than it actually processes an action (as many different portlets can be on one page, only one might process an action while all might display/render.